# Synchronize Production database in each deployment to Staging Heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku, production, staging

I want to sync Staging and Production databases in every deploy to Staging.

Pseudo code of what I want to accomplish.

```
1. backup production database.
2. restore staging database with the production one.
3. run migrations into the staging database.
```

I don't quite understand how to do it in Heroku. The filesystem is read only I can't install `mysql-client and do a`mysqldump`.

What I am gonna try is to make a request to another server that will do the trick (this server has the mysql-client installed).

My stack is Node.js

any other thoughts on this?